# Gaussian variables and conditional expectation calculation

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Let $X,Y,Z$ be gaussian variables with zero mean. If we know the following
$$E[Y\mid X=x,Z=z]=ax+bz$$
for some a and b, how can one calculate the following integral

$$\int y \int p(y \mid x,z)p(z) dzdy$$

Answer (score 2):

By definition, $$\int yp(y \mid x,z)dy=E[Y\mid X=x,Z=z]=ax+bz$$

Hence $$\int y \int p(y \mid x,z)p(z) dzdy$$  $$=\int p(z)\int p(y|x,z).ydydz$$
$$=\int p(z) \mathbb E[Y|X=x,Z=z]dz$$
$$=\int p(z) (ax+bz)dz$$
$$=ax+b\int p(z).z dz$$
$$=ax$$

Since $z$ is Gaussian with $0$ mean.

Comment: which is what you might guess: integrate over $z$ given $E[Z]=0$ and it might disappear from $E[Y\mid X=x,Z=z]=ax+bz$ to give $E[Y\mid X=x]=ax$

Comment: What did you use for the first equality to switch the order of integration?